# Is there an action opposite to ImageButton.setImageSource() on android?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I need to get the image's resource of image button.
Did someone have way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there is an api for that.

Comment: `ImageButton.setImageSource()` or `ImageButton.setImageResource()`?

Comment: maby i dont was clear i want to get the name of the image that the image button showing at specific moment

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton does not have a setImageSource() function.  If you are looking to get the drawable back out of the ImageButton you can call imageButton.getDrawable();